# Eclipse MAC - Comment / Uncomment - keyboard shortcut

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse-pdt

I just upgraded by eclipse PDT and can't use the keyboard shortcut

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to comment /uncomment

any help would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i'm not really sure what happend when I upgraded but the solution is as follows-

1. head over to - http://sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/releases/51060 - and download the file "org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar"
2. open up your eclipse folder - /Applications/ecplise/plugins
3. replace the "org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar" with the one you just downloaded
4. open terminal
5. navigate to your eclipse folder - /Applications/eclipse
6. type "./eclipse -clean"

This fixes up your keyboard short cut but in my case I need to re-map from command + / to command + shift + c

Thanks to slomojo for this-
7. Go to windows -> preferences -> general settings -> keys and update the following
http://img703.imageshack.us/img703/264/bildschirmfoto20110915u.png

hope this helps.

Comment: went to download the file again but couldn't find it, had to use: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/tools/pdt/updates/2.2/milestones/plugins/org.eclipse.php.ui_2.2.1.v20101001-2300.jar

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in Eclipse > Preferences > General Settings > Keys

The shortcut may have been overridden by another one.

Answer (score 1):

**Single line**

Toggle of same keys

*comment* <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>Cmd</kbd> +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  + <kbd>C</kbd>

**Multiline**

*comment* <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

*uncomment* <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> (note the backslash)

Hope this helps!

Comment: its for Windows, its asked for Mac.

Comment: @Chandra Sorry, I could not spoon feed you but every mac user must know the windows ctrl equivalent in mac. However, without complaining you can always edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mai 2022 on my MacBook Pro 2019 => select the code you want to comment or uncomment and do the following: press `command 7` to comment and `command 7` to uncomment